# How do I run my website files with Xampp? (error message)

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I just got Xampp up and running and was able to run a simple 'hello world' php form. From there I copied all the files from my website (around 55mb) and tried to run index.php, but my web browser just displays, "**Error establishing a database connection**". The website itself is working, but just not in Xampp. As far as I know it's on one server (or at least I only had to use one ftp) and it is set up through WordPress. My website files consist of php, js, css, and html. Any ideas of what I should do or where the error might be? Thanks!!!

Comment: Try opening localhost/phpmyadmin in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

To get your Wordpress site to work, there is a mysql component in Xampp.You need to turn it on. Then go to localhost/phpmyadmin adn create a DB for your website. Once in the DB you need to import the DB of your running site and try loading the index.php page. That should make it work.